# YOCTO : recipe to insert a script in init.d doesn't work

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would insert a startuo.sh script in \etc\init.d\ directory of my devices.
To do that I use this *.bb file:

```
DESCRIPTION = "System start up script"
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://startup.sh"

do_install() {

      install -d ${D}/etc/init.d/
      install -m 0755 ${THISDIR}/files/startup.sh ${D}/etc/init.d/startup.sh
}
```

the bitbake works without error and warning but the ev board is not able to bring-up. It is blocked during boot phase.
The problem should be in this recipes because without it, the board goes up and running

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`THISDIR` points to your recipe's folder.

It is recommended to use the file from the workding directory of the recipe.

Your file is located under `WORKDIR` because it is unpacked there based on your `SRC_URI` variable.

So, you need to change your recipe to:

```
DESCRIPTION = "System start up script"
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://startup.sh"

do_install() {
      install -d ${D}/etc/init.d/
      install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/startup.sh ${D}/etc/init.d/startup.sh
#                         ^
#                         |
# Here --------------------
}

# Do not forget to specify the package's files:
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/init.d/startup.sh"
```

**EDIT**

I think you need to apply init.d service rules.

Check this [link](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/update-rc-d_class.html) on how to use `update-rc.d` class for init.d scripts with Yocto.

Comment: Hi Talel, I've done your update but doesn't work, the problem is the same

Comment: Please provide more information about the boot failure, and the content of the script.

Comment: my startup.sh script contains only:                                                     
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test"

Comment: About the boot, the last messages shown on serial link is :                                        Finished update UTMP with result OK.                                                                                                         In a correct boot this is the last message before the login prompt

Comment: Check my **EDIT**

Comment: Thanks, but the problem seem other. I'm able to put my *.bin file in a fs directory, so I try to put in same dir a *.txt file using the *.bb schema above. The boot is blocked.